# Excel - Help! (You've entered too many arguments for this function)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

=IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$W$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$w:$w),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$X$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!x:x),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$Y$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!y:y),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$Z$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!z:z),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AA$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!Aa:Aa),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AB$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!ab:Ab),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AC$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ac:$ac),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AD$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ad:$ad),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AE$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ae:$ae),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AF$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$af:$af),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AG$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ag:$ag),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AH$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ah:$ah),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AI$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ai:$ai),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AJ$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$aj:$aj),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AK$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ak:$ak),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AL$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$al:$al),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AM$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$am:$am),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AN$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$an:$an),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AO$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ao:$ao),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AP$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ap:$ap,IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AQ$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$aq:$aq),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AR$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ar:$ar),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AS$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$as:$as),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AT$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$at:$at),IF($C$3=BuySellBillable!$AU$6,SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$au:$au),0)))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Well, there *are* too many arguments (see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) for a list of Excel limits). That being said, there is surely a better way to go about it that tons of nested `IF` statements (maybe `SUMIFS`). Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1364037/edit) to describe what you're trying to accomplish. Some sample data and the expected outcome would also be useful

Comment: This looks like it could be speech-to-text output from a stock trading floor!

Comment: I think unnecessarily you have use so many IFs , this can be testes in better way  using  other logical test options,, I would like to suggest  you share  some sample data with us or share the file on cloud, help us to fix it soon. !! ☺

Comment: I was trying to effectively amalgamate a H Look up and a V Look Up. I need to find precise figures in a unfortunately uneditable table with 23 columns and 300 rows where the data (The result also have to be fluid as the data in the tables is  frequently sorted and filtered by different factors)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a close bracket in this part of your formula:

```
SUMIF(BuySellBillable!$A:$A,'DL Analysis'!$B7,BuySellBillable!$ap:$ap,
                                                           right here^
```